# How to change opacity in Highcharts of particular range

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I have a series, I want to change the opacity to 0.2 on xaxis from 23 to 52 in Highcharts for the below data

On xaxis from 23 to 52 data points opacity should be 0.2, for the rest it will be untouched.

```
series: [{
    data: [23, 42, 52, 47, 64],
    zoneAxis: 'x',
    zones: [{
        value: 1.00001,
    }, {
        value: 2.00001,
    }, {
        value: 3.00001,
    }]
}]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use semi-transparent colours to achieve that - RGBA or HEX.

```
series: [{
    data: [23, 42, 52, 47, 64],
    zoneAxis: 'x',
    zones: [{
        value: 1.00001,
        color:  'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2)'
    }, {
        value: 2.00001,
        color:  'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)'
    }, {
        value: 3.00001,
        color: 'green'
    }, {
        color: 'red'
    }]
}]
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1b0zsw5r/

**EDIT:**
The zones opacity option is not available from the API, but you can extend Higcharts to achieve that. Here is a sample plugin:

```
(function(H) {
  H.Point.prototype.getZone = function() {

    function addAlpha(color, opacity) {
      const _opacity = Math.round(Math.min(Math.max(opacity || 1, 0), 1) * 255);
      return color + _opacity.toString(16).toUpperCase();
    }

    var series = this.series,
      zones = series.zones,
      zoneAxis = series.zoneAxis || 'y',
      zone,
      i = 0;

    zone = zones[i];
    while (this[zoneAxis] >= zone.value) {
      zone = zones[++i];
    }

    function customZone(noOpacityColor) {
      let isOpacityColor = addAlpha(noOpacityColor, zone.opacity).slice(0, 9);
      if (zone.opacity) {
        zone.color = isOpacityColor
      } else {
        this.color = noOpacityColor
      }
    }

    if (!this.nonZonedColor) {
      this.nonZonedColor = this.color;
    }

    if (zone && zone.color && !this.options.color) {
      customZone(zone.color)
      this.color = zone.color;
    } else {
      customZone(this.nonZonedColor)
    }

    return zone;
  };
}(Highcharts));
```

*You can use the above plugin with no colour defined or colour in HEX format.*

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6s50b7ot/

**Extending Highcharts:**

https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: Hey edited the question here, if you see series ,line colors are not defined , just opacity we need to change now ,how to do that?

Comment: Hi, In that case, it will be necessary to add a custom plugin. I edited my answer! Regards!

Comment: I have a range in zone, for example 2 to 3 in x axis ? How will i add that range also ?

Comment: You can use zones with this plugin as before. I've added only the possibility to use opacity https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/L2orxjw6/ . If something is not clear, please share the config you want to use